# Depending on a Probability Measure.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

In Jun Shao's Mathematical Statistics, the author tries to frame statistics in a more general setting than I'm used to.

For example, by his definition, the *Population* is a probability measure $P$. So far so good...
Then in some definitions, he talks about "depending on $P$".
Here are some examples:

1. In factorization theorem for a sufficient statistics $T(X)$, he states
   $$ \frac{dP}{d\nu}=g_P(T(x)) h(x)$$
   that $g_P$ depends on $P$, but $h(x)$ does not.
2. In the definition for ancillary statistic, he states that the distribution of that statistic does not depend on the population $P$.

I'm used to these definitions being given w.r.t. parameters. I'm assuming that given this level of generality, these definitions may also work for non-parametric distribution families.

What does it mean to depend on the distribution, on the previous definitions?